# jamesfebin:azure-blob-upload: TypeError: file.azureUpload is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, meteor

I try to use on a sample file uploader (https://github.com/pc-magas/dummy-azure-file-upload) the https://atmospherejs.com/jamesfebin/azure-blob-upload

So I created the following file named `imports/api/FileUpload.js`:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import FileUploadSetings from '../settings/fileUploadSettings.js'

const UploadedFile = new Mongo.Collection('file');

Meteor.methods({
  'fileStorage.uploadFile'(file) {
      console.log("File To be uploaded",file)

      var response=file.azureUpload(file.name,FileUploadSetings.account,FileUploadSetings.key,FileUploadSetings.container)

      return response
  }
});
```

And the appropriate frontend:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { UploadedFile } from '../api/FileUpload.js';

class File extends Component {

  changeFile(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var targetElem=e.target
    files = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
    file = files.files[0]
    AzureFile.upload(file,'fileStorage.uploadFile',function(err,value){
        if(err){
          console.log(err)
          throw err;
          return;
        }
        console.log(value);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={ this.changeFile.bind(this) }>
        <label>
          <input id="fileUpload" type="file" name="file" />
        </label>

        <button type="submit">UploadFile</button>
      </form>
    )
  }

}

export default File;
```

But on my browser I get the following error:

> Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'fileStorage.uploadFile' TypeError: file.azureUpload is not a function
>   Καταγραφή στοίβας:
>   fileStorage.uploadFile@http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=130e7c3d782ccd6552701f8726699ac4a8c57f12:85:24
>   apply/stubReturnValue<@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=c9ca22092a3137a7096e8ab722ba5ab8eedb9aec:4076:20
>   withValue@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=27829e936d09beae3149ecfbf3332c42ccb1596f:1077:17
>   apply@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=c9ca22092a3137a7096e8ab722ba5ab8eedb9aec:4067:31
>   readNext/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/jamesfebin_azure-blob-upload.js?hash=8cbf5c2696876a426eda4183be8f4ce83c709a97:206:9
>   read/reader.onload@http://localhost:3000/packages/jamesfebin_azure-blob-upload.js?hash=8cbf5c2696876a426eda4183be8f4ce83c709a97:146:6
>    fileStorage.uploadFile@http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=130e7c3d782ccd6552701f8726699ac4a8c57f12:85:24
>   apply/stubReturnValue<@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=c9ca22092a3137a7096e8ab722ba5ab8eedb9aec:4076:20
>   withValue@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=27829e936d09beae3149ecfbf3332c42ccb1596f:1077:17
>   apply@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=c9ca22092a3137a7096e8ab722ba5ab8eedb9aec:4067:31
>   readNext/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/jamesfebin_azure-blob-upload.js?hash=8cbf5c2696876a426eda4183be8f4ce83c709a97:206:9
>   read/reader.onload@http://localhost:3000/packages/jamesfebin_azure-blob-upload.js?hash=8cbf5c2696876a426eda4183be8f4ce83c709a97:146:6
>     meteor.js:932:11

Do you have any Idea why does it happen amd how I will solve it?

Comment: Which version of meteor are you using?